# HttpWebRequest failed with certificates when open visual studio in admin mode

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest, .net-5

I am working on a .NET5 Web project and is required to use an already build library (developed in .NET Framework). In the library, we are hitting API endpoints and have the option to use username/password or cert authentication. When I run the project in the visual studio without admin mode, I successfully authenticate using the provided certificates however when I open the visual studio in administrator mode, I'm getting **400 Bad Request** error. I want to run the project in admin mode as we want to deploy it on the docker container and I want to debug the app before creating the image.

Here is the code to create certificates

```cs
public X509Certificate2Collection LoadPersonalCertificates(bool ForceLoadAll = false)
{
    try
    {
        var certificatePath = Path.Combine(@"path-to-cert.pem");
        var certificateContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(certificatePath);

        var certificateCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificateCollection.Import(GetCertificateFromPEM(certificateContent, PEMSections.Certificate));
        var rsaGenerator = RSA.Create();

        rsaGenerator.ImportFromPem(cPEMPrivateKeyHeader + Convert.ToBase64String(GetCertificateFromPEM(certificateContent, PEMSections.PrivateKey)) + cPEMPrivateKeyFooter);

        var cert = certificateCollection[0];
        cert = cert.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsaGenerator);
        cert = new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "pfx password"), "pfx password");
        certificateCollection.Add(cert);
        certificateCollection.RemoveAt(0);
        
        return certificateCollection;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex);
        
        throw;
    }
}
```

Code to parse the .pem file

```cs
#region Certification Helpers

private string strPEMCertificateFileContent = "";
private const string cPEMCertificateHeader = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"; // this is Certificate header 
private const string cPEMCertificateFooter = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----"; // this is certificate footer
private const string cPEMPrivateKeyHeader = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"; // this is private certificate header
private const string cPEMPrivateKeyFooter = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"; // this is private certificate footer

/// <summary>
/// This Will Extract The Certificate From PEM Certificate File And Return Bytes To Construct The X509Certificate
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pemString">Provide The PEM File Content</param>
/// <param name="section">Provide Which Section To Extract, e.g CERTIFICATE Or CA Certificate</param>
/// <returns>Returns Extracted Bytes</returns>
public byte[] GetCertificateFromPEM(string pemString, PEMSections section)
{
    try
    {
        int intStartIndex = 0; // will hold the start index of PEM ceritificate header
        int intEndIndex = 0;

        // check for requested PEM Certificate Section
        switch (section)
        {
            case PEMSections.CA_Certificate: // get the CA Certificate From PEM File
                {

                    // get the zero-based index of last occurance for certificate header using ordinal sorting option
                    intStartIndex = pemString.LastIndexOf(cPEMCertificateHeader, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    if (intStartIndex < 0)
                        return null; // if the start index value is less than zero then its not found so we return null
                    intStartIndex += cPEMCertificateHeader.Length; // adding the header length to start index
                                                                   // get the zero-based index of first occurance for certificate footer using ordinal sorting option and exclude the header length for getting string between the header and footer
                    intEndIndex = pemString.IndexOf(cPEMCertificateFooter, intStartIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal) - intStartIndex;
                    if (intEndIndex < 0)
                        return null; // if the end index value is less than zero then its not found so we return null
                                     // convert the base64 extracted string using start index and end index to bytes and return them
                    break;
                }

            case PEMSections.Certificate: // get the certificate from PEM File
                {

                    // get the zero-based index of first occurance for certificate header using ordinal sorting option
                    intStartIndex = pemString.IndexOf(cPEMCertificateHeader, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    if (intStartIndex < 0)
                        return null; // if the start index value is less than zero then its not found so we return null
                    intStartIndex += cPEMCertificateHeader.Length; // adding the header length to start index
                                                                   // get the zero-based index of first occurance for certificate footer using ordinal sorting option and exclude the header length for getting string between the header and footer
                    intEndIndex = pemString.IndexOf(cPEMCertificateFooter, intStartIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal) - intStartIndex;
                    if (intEndIndex < 0)
                        return null; // if the end index value is less than zero then its not found so we return null
                    break;
                }

            case PEMSections.PrivateKey: //get the privatekey from PEM File
                {
                    // get the zero-based index of first occurance for certificate header using ordinal sorting option
                    intStartIndex = pemString.IndexOf(cPEMPrivateKeyHeader, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    if (intStartIndex < 0)
                        return null; // if the start index value is less than zero then its not found so we return null
                    intStartIndex += cPEMPrivateKeyHeader.Length; // adding the header length to start index
                                                                  // get the zero-based index of first occurance for certificate footer using ordinal sorting option and exclude the header length for getting string between the header and footer
                    intEndIndex = pemString.IndexOf(cPEMPrivateKeyFooter, intStartIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal) - intStartIndex;
                    if (intEndIndex < 0)
                        return null; // if the end index value is less than zero then its not found so we return null
                    break;
                }

            default:
                {
                    return null;
                }
        }

        // convert the base64 extracted string using start index and end index to bytes and return them
        return Convert.FromBase64String(pemString.Substring(intStartIndex, intEndIndex));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This Enum Will Hold The Certificate Sections Of PEM Certificate
/// </summary>
public enum PEMSections
{
    Certificate = 1,
    CA_Certificate = 2,
    PrivateKey = 3
}
#endregion
```

Code to make the HTTP get request to API endpoint

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This Will Make GET Request To Server And Return The Content That Received From Server
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strURL">Provide The URL Address</param>
/// <returns>Returns Contents As String</returns>
private string MakeGETRequest(ref string strURL)
{
    // check if the url is null
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cPAKCloud_URL))
    {
        return cFUNCTION_ERROR;
    }

    if (NoSSLVerification)
    {
        // this will be used to bypass server unsecure certificates
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AcceptAllCertifications;
    }

    ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false; // disable the certificate revoke check 

    // setting the server security protocol for connecting to server
    if (SetSecurityProtocol)
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    reqPakAPI = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL) as HttpWebRequest; // creating the new request for provided URL
    reqPakAPI.Method = "GET"; // setting the method of http
    reqPakAPI.UserAgent = cHTTPUserAgent; // setting the useragent for library
    if (e_AuthenticationType == AuthenticationType.CERTIFICATES)
    {
        reqPakAPI.CookieContainer = respCoookies;
        reqPakAPI.ClientCertificates = certCollection;   // assigning certificates collection to request certificates
    }
    else if (e_AuthenticationType == AuthenticationType.BASIC)
    {
        reqPakAPI.CookieContainer = respCoookies;
    }

    // using try catch to avoid any errors
    try
    {

        // getting response from url and assigning that response to resPakAPI
        using (HttpWebResponse resPakAPI = reqPakAPI.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(resPakAPI.Cookies["csrftoken"].Value) == false)
            {
                sCSRFToken = resPakAPI.Cookies["csrftoken"].Value;
            }
            // creating new stream reader to read the stream response
            using (var strReader = new StreamReader(resPakAPI.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                // setting the content of page to strHTTPclntResponse
                strHTTPclntResponse = strReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.TrustFailure)
        {
            LastErrorMessage = "The server sent an invalid SSL certificate, Please Enable NoSSLVerify if you want to skip this error";
            return cFUNCTION_ERROR;
        }

        string strTest = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        if (strTest.Contains("<title>Under Maintenance</title>"))
        {
            LastErrorMessage = "Under Maintenance";
            return cFUNCTION_ERROR;
        }
        else if (strHTTPclntResponse.Contains("<title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title>"))
        {
            LastErrorMessage = "No required SSL certificate was sent";
            return cFUNCTION_ERROR;
        }

        // setting the exception message to CurrentErrorMessage property and inner exception if found
        LastErrorMessage = ex.Message + ((ex.InnerException == null) ? "" : Constants.vbCrLf + "Inner: " + ex.InnerException.Message);
    }

    // return the content in strHTTPclntResponse as string
    return strHTTPclntResponse;
}
```

Can anyone please help me what I'm doing wrong (As is it working in non-admin mode but non in admin-mode). Thanks in advance